# create stripe paiement intent with a manual confirmation_method result in a succed status instead of requires_action

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I've followed this doc : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously
Which is very clear but surprise, when launching on server side:

```
const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        payment_method: paymentMethodId,
        amount: 5999,
        currency: 'eur',
        confirmation_method: 'manual',
        confirm: true
      });
```

I get :

```
{
  id: 'pi_3LuNKVDLnKFDevPq2OpR1nMX',
  object: 'payment_intent',
  amount: 5999,
  amount_capturable: 0,
  amount_details: { tip: {} },
  amount_received: 5999,
  application: null,
  application_fee_amount: null,
  automatic_payment_methods: null,
  canceled_at: null,
  cancellation_reason: null,
  capture_method: 'automatic',
  charges: {
    object: 'list',
    data: [ [Object] ],
    has_more: false,
    total_count: 1,
    url: '/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_3LuNKVDLnKFDevPq2OpR1nMX'
  },
  client_secret: 'pi_3LuNKVDLnKFDevPq2OpR1nMX_secret_jpNtP1aYILlixGML8gSd3CvNk',
  confirmation_method: 'manual',
  created: 1666128487,
  currency: 'eur',
  customer: null,
  description: null,
  invoice: null,
  last_payment_error: null,
  livemode: false,
  metadata: {},
  next_action: null,
  on_behalf_of: null,
  payment_method: 'pm_1LuNKUDLnKFDevPqUMLAxk9k',
  payment_method_options: {
    card: {
      installments: null,
      mandate_options: null,
      network: null,
      request_three_d_secure: 'automatic'
    }
  },
  payment_method_types: [ 'card' ],
  processing: null,
  receipt_email: null,
  review: null,
  setup_future_usage: null,
  shipping: null,
  source: null,
  statement_descriptor: null,
  statement_descriptor_suffix: null,
  status: 'succeeded',
  transfer_data: null,
  transfer_group: null
}
```

Basically, it's like the final confirmation in my mind without making further steps (I just need to make the transfert on server side) but is that behavior normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely reason as to why your Payment Intent’s status is not set to `requires_action` is due to using a Test card that does not require a 3DS authentication. The cards that you’d want to use to test 3DS flow are listed [here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing?numbers-or-method-or-token=card-numbers#three-ds-cards). If the card does not require further action, then it is normal that the Payment Intent status shows `succeeded`.